# Существует ли мат. анализ дискретных (прерывистых) переменных/функций?

Tags: математика

Существует ли дисциплина, изучающая прерывистых (дискретные, не случайные) переменные, величины, функции и т.д. теми же исчислениями или аналогичными, что используются в классическом (основанной на непрерывности) мат. анализе? 
(Дифференциальное и интегральное исчисление)

Данный вопрос возник при изучении теории вероятностей и математической статистики - когда затронули ДСВ и НСВ - только на сей раз интересуют не случайные, а конкретные (действительные) дискретные величины (в т.ч. переменные) и функции - с позиции соответствующего для них анализа, исчисления.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть здесь: https://studopedia.info/1-113128.html

Comment: Теория меры, возможно? Во всяком случае, для интеграла Лебега, например, подынтегральная функция вполне может быть дискретной.

Answer (score 0):

Дискретная математика. Например, существует понятие дифференцирования и интегрирования булевых функций.